# need help on reverse a sentence using stack

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to reverse my sentence. For example, hello = olleh. I have written the code but there is something wrong which I am trying to figure out. Can you please help me with this problem?
 This is my code.

```
import java.util.*;    
    public class ArrayStack<T> implements StackADT<T>       
    {      
        private final static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;    
        private int top;  
        private T[] stack;

        /**
         * Creates an empty stack using the default capacity.     
        */

        public ArrayStack()
        {
            this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
        }    

        /**
         * Creates an empty stack using the specified capacity.     
         * @param initialCapacity the initial size of the array 
        */

        public ArrayStack(int initialCapacity)
        {
            top = 0;
            stack = (T[])(new Object[initialCapacity]);       
        }    

        /**
         * Adds the specified element to the top of this stack, expanding
         * the capacity of the array if necessary.
         * @param element generic element to be pushed onto stack
        */

        public void push(T element)
        {
            if (size() == stack.length) 
            expandCapacity();        
            stack[top] = element;
            top++;
        }    

        /**
         * Creates a new array to store the contents of this stack with
         * twice the capacity of the old one.
        */

        private void expandCapacity()
        {
            stack = Arrays.copyOf(stack, stack.length * 2);   
        }    

        /**
         * Removes the element at the top of this stack and returns a
         * reference to it. 
         * @return element removed from top of stack    
         * @throws EmptyCollectionException if stack is empty 
        */

        public T pop() throws EmptyCollectionException
        {
            if (isEmpty())
                throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");        
            top--;
            result = stack[top];
            stack[top] = null; 
            return result;
        }


        /**
         * Returns a reference to the element at the top of this stack.
         * The element is not removed from the stack.  
         * @return element on top of stack
         * @throws EmptyCollectionException if stack is empty
        */

        public T peek() throws EmptyCollectionException
        {
            if (isEmpty())
                throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");        
            return stack[top-1];
        }   

        /**     
         * Returns true if this stack is empty and false otherwise. 
         * @return true if this stack is empty
        */

        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
             return stack.length == 0;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the number of elements in this stack.
         * @return the number of elements in the stack
        */

        public int size()
        {
            return top;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {    
            ArrayStack<Character> stack = new ArrayStack<Character>();
            String sentence = " ", word;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a sentence:");
            sentence= in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Reversing each word:");
            Scanner sentenceScanner = new Scanner(sentence);

            while(sentenceScanner.hasNext())
            {
                word = sentenceScanner.next();       
                for(int i= 0; i<word.length(); i++)        
                {
                    System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
                }

                for(int i = word.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
                {
                    stack.pop();
                }   
             }    
         }   
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you start by using a `Stack<Char>`?

Comment: What's wrong with it? What error are you getting or what isn't behaving right?

Comment: what is you mean by _something wrong_?

Comment: I did that. ArrayStack<Character> stack = new ArrayStack<Character>();

Comment: can you give us a specific error code?

Comment: @Hugo, It is not reversing the word. For example, if I type today on the terminal window, it says today instead of yadot.

Comment: No the builtin `Stack<Character>` of java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: @ylun The error is that it is not reversing the word. I am trying to figure out what the error is. Is it something to do with stack.pop sentence I typed in the end?

Comment: @CommuSoft. This is the code that the teacher gave us.

Comment: In order to pop something from the stack, you need to push something onto the stack, i don't see that happen in your code.

Comment: Did you implement the Stack yourself? For instance the cast `(T[])` is very error prone. Internally represent the array as a `Object[]`, only communicate with `T` to the outside world.

Comment: @CommuSoft. No I did not. The teacher gave us that code. The only part I did was from  public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: I'm not going to give you the exact answer since it's an assignment. I'm just going to tell you how to get it. You need to loop through each letter in the word, pushing them onto your stack. Then, as you pop them off one at a time, create a new word.

Comment: Use your stack. You have functions in your stack to push and pop.

Comment: @Hugo I was able to reverse the sentence but now it is showing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: @lakshman it says java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at System.out.print(stack.pop()); and T result = stack[top];

Comment: There's probably a problem with the way you're storing the characters on the stack. I'm not going to give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are never adding anything to your stack, which is why it is not printing in reverse order; instead, you are explicitly printing the characters in order right here:

```
        for(int i= 0; i<word.length(); i++)

        {

            System.out.print(word.charAt(i));

        }
```

You are just looping through the word, in order, and printing each character. I believe what you meant to do was add the character to the stack instead, an then print out the characters in the next loop that you have where you are popping them from the stack.

So, your code should look more like this:

```
 for(int i= 0; i<word.length(); i++)        
  {
     stack.push(word.charAt(i));
  }

  while (!stack.isEmpty())   //instead of for(int i = word.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
  {
     System.out.print(stack.pop());
  }
```

Comment: So what am I supposed to do?

Comment: I edited the answer with an example of code that should work to add the characters to the stack and then print them as you pop them.

Comment: @user3339580 Looking at your code i think it should be `sentence.length()` instead of `word.length()`

Comment: I'm guessing that has to do with the following lines in your `pop` method: 
                result = stack[top];
                stack[top] = null;

Comment: @Jsdodgers I was able to fix the null problem. But now it says java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at System.out.print(stack.pop()); and T result = stack[top];